# What is the efficient way to use nested dynamic component in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js, data-structures, vue-dynamic-components

Right now, i am using dynamic component element in a **for loop** to render a page, like this:

```
//_.vue file
<div v-for="(component,index) in allComponentsInPage" :key="index">
      <component
        :is="component.name"
        :v-bind="component.fields"
        />
  </div>
```

allComponentsInPage array will have all the components in the page  as object(each having two key value pair), **name** is the name of component and **fields** is the props of the component.

```
allComponentsInPage: [
            {
                name: 'FormComponent',
                fields: {username: 'Ashish',phone: '9090909090'}
            },
            {
                name: 'ButtonComponent',
                fields: {buttonText: 'Click here',link: 'https://www.something.com'}
            }
        ],
```

but now i want to create a new component which will have an an array of components(can be any) as a prop that will be rendered. So, do i have to use another **for loop** with dynamic component in that new component that i am creating.

```
//MultipleComponent.vue
<div v-for="(nestedComp,index) in new newComponentHavingMultipleComponentAsProp" :key="index">
      <component
        :is="nestedComp.name"
        :v-bind="nestedComp.fields" 
        />
  </div>
```

Structure of **newComponentHavingMultipleComponentAsProp** is same as **allComponentsInPage**.

Is there any other way(other than nested **for** **loops**) to implement such components.
I tried with nested **for** loop and it works fine but does not seems to be right approach.

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue with `for` loop ? As each object in an array is containing a component. I think `v-for` is a good way to achieve that.

Comment: "does not seems to be right approach" - why? It's unknown why this is done in the first place, could be XY problem. The idea looks strange. nested for is reasonable. Alternatively, can be done in render function and looped the way you want. It's unknown why there should be a nested array. It could be flattened first

Comment: make sure imported all componets in that page FormComponent, ButtonComponent

Comment: This is the correct way. If you want an alternative you can use render function and use js `map`/iterators to return the built component